Why does the Kieboom characterization of shape is restricted only to paracompact spaces?
Borsuk founded shape theory as an extension of homotopy theory, appropriate for spaces with bad local properties. Borsuks definition was applied only to compact metric spaces. Later, this was generalized by different mathematicians to other spaces: CW, compact Hausdorff, metric spaces etc., until Mardesic generalized it to arbitrary topological spaces (see this).
Through time there have been different approaches on definig shape (fundamental sequence, inverse systems, multivalued functions, etc.). In Kieboom article, he is using the approximate nets, but he restricts his definition only to paracompact spaces. This article is refered to the article "Multivalued maps and shape for paracompacta" authored by M. A. Morón and F. R. Ruiz del Portal (see here) which is not avaliable online.
Kieboom first defines $\mathcal{V}$ continuity (continuity up to some covering), $\mathcal{V}$-homotopy and then approximate nets by using coverings of paracompact spaces. However, while the definition makes sense for arbitrary topological spaces, I cannot see why his definition is restricted only to paracompact spaces.

Paracompactness is used in the proofs of several statements (Proposition 1.6, Lemma 1.8, Corollary 1.9, in only the first section). The basic definitions themselves don't require paracompactness and seem to be stated for arbitrary topological spaces. As far as I can tell, Kieboom is quite careful to state where he uses paracompactness.

In the following paper https://doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/0354-5180/2015/0354-51801510199S.pdf the same definitions are provided but no paracompactness and normal covers are used. However, it is stated that paracompact spaces and proximate nets form a category.
